# Header and Footer is not converting to pdf using POI.jar

Tags: java, pdf, docx, xdocreport

I am using **XDOCReport** to convert **DOCX to PDF**.But **Only body content has been converted to PDF** rather than converting the whole document (with Header and Footer).

the following code has been used to convert docx to pdf

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(is);
PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputPdfFilePath));
PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
```

The final output **pdf document has Body content and the blank space for header and footer**. need to convert whole document to pdf.

Comment: [Apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/allclasses-frame.html) does not contain any `PdfConverter`. So it is not clear what you are using here.

Comment: it is there please check with this package "org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter"

Comment: This package is not part of `apache poi`.

Comment: I am using this jar "org.apache.poi/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.0.jar" to convert

Comment: This package is part of an old version of [xdocreport](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport). They were hijacking the POI namespace at one point, but that has been corrected. Please upgrade your packages and report problems to the appropriate project.

Comment: @vijaykumarg - Did you ever get this resolved?  I am facing this issue today with the 2.0.2 version.  Specifically - the formatting in the DOCX header is not being preserved and the image that I have in the header is completely lost.

Comment: @ivan_drago also wondering whether any solution was found for this because I'm coming across the exact same issue as well - images in headers and footers not persisting in the PDF output.

Comment: @AToe - We ended up going with Cloudmersive API.  The alternative that we were evaluating was the documents4j API.  In the end Cloudmersive was just EASY to use since it's simply calling out to their API, whereas documents4j requires more work in setting up a remote server with Microsoft Word running on it.